# Python - MICE imputation - statsmodels

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, missing-data, statsmodels, imputation

**Question:**
Are there any MICE methods in Python statsmodels that I can use for imputing missing datapoints with a single equation?(not with Chained Equations)

To my observation, It seems that statsmodels provide "statsmodels.imputation.mice.MICE" method, but this one is for "Multiple Imputation with Chained Equations".

I would like "Multiple Imputation with a single Equation" because I have a dataset with 237 columns & 219395 rows.

Comment: Do you have missing values in only one column?

Comment: Multiple columns

Comment: Then what is "Multiple Imputation with a single Equation" ? How do you want to impute values for multiple columns?